# php class get variables from another function in an array

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have a class in php. Inside class I have a function called `setContent()`. Inside that I have multiple variable with values. I have taken those variable values and stored them in an array.In another function I wanted to get all the variables stored in an array. So my code is like this

```
class foo{
    public function setContent() {
        global $my_array;
        $var1 = 'variable 1';
        $var2 = 'variable 2';
        $var3 = 'variable 3';
        $var4 = 'variable 4';
        $var5 = 'variable 5';
        new_array = array();
        $my_array = array_push($new_array, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
    }

    public function getContent() {
        global $my_array;
        var_dump($my_array);
    }
}
```

But when I am doing `var_dump($my_array)`. Its showing `NULL`. So can someone tell me how to get those variables inside other function in an array. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: you should declare variable outside functions, `global $my_array = array();`

Comment: This is circumventing everything that classes are designed for. Don't use globals. Store the variable as a property of the class.

Comment: Since you're using classes, read about the full scope of possibilities, in particular properties: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 5):

You can set the array for use by declaring it inside your class. Then, you just refer to `$this` rather than the global var.

```
class foo{
    public $my_array; # new bit here

    public function setContent() {
        # global $my_array; take this bit out
        $var1 = 'variable 1';
        $var2 = 'variable 2';
        $var3 = 'variable 3';
        $var4 = 'variable 4';
        $var5 = 'variable 5';
        $new_array = array();
        $this->my_array = array_push($new_array, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
    }

    public function getContent() {
        var_dump($this->my_array);
    }
}
```

Because the array is now part of the `foo` object, we can now refer to it all along. If you were to keep it public you could do something like the following:

```
$f = new foo();
print_r($f->my_array);
```

Comment: Supply a description and this answer would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you implements your class like these :

```
class foo{

    public $my_array = array();

    public function setContent() {
        $var1 = 'variable 1';
        $var2 = 'variable 2';
        $var3 = 'variable 3';
        $var4 = 'variable 4';
        $var5 = 'variable 5';

        array_push($this->my_array, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
    }

    public function getContent() {
        var_dump($this->my_array);
    }
}
```

I think this is a bad practice to use global variables in OOP.

In fact i recommend to rewrite your getContent function :

```
public function getContent() {
    return $this->my_array;
}
```

and instanciate your object :

```
$my_object = new foo();
$foo->setContent();
var_dump ($foo->getContent());
```

I will improve class reusability

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php

You've to write 
`array_push($new_array, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);`

because `array_push` return the length of the array (an integer, not the array !). So you can't write:

```
$myarray = array_push($myarray, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
```